# Determine File Type of attachments stored in SQL Server as varbinary(MAX)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, file, ms-access-2010

I need some help. We migrated an Access database to SQL Server. One column had attachment data the `Attachment` data type in MS Access. The MS Access application is being replaces by an ASP.NET web application.

This data now lives in a column of data type `varbinary(MAX)`, there is no indication of the file name and or type (most attachments are Excel, Word and PDF docs).

In my ASP.Net application I am using a data reader that will allow users to retrieve the attachments by downloading them using a browser. (I have a new table for new attachments that contains the full file name and content type, and when present it works like a charm). Without the file types, all attachments come across as xml/garbles data files like shown in this image below (can't yet post images, been a long time reader, first contribution. Here is the text in which I had planned to highlight some key values:

> - ÿÿÿÿ**WorksheetExcel.Sheet.12****Access.OLE2Link**¾ÐÏà¡±á>þÿ þÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ]þÿÿÿþÿÿÿ   !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\þÿÿÿþÿÿÿÿÿRoot EntryÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿàÆ©÷òï…ÝŒkˆZ‚Å7Ï€Ole ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿCompObjÿÿÿÿeOlePres000ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿš­  þÿÿÿþÿÿÿþÿÿ‹ÀF CENTRA~1.XLSÿÿ­ÞHB**Central Dispatch Process Map.xlsx**ºÀF'**C:\Users\MA~1\Desktop\CENTRA~1.XLS**ÿÿ­Þ]|**C:\Users\ine\Desktop\Central Dispatch Process Map.xlsx**ÕLÀFƒ •Æh5)ÏBy>*Ï¦c{>*ÏS5ŽŒ2S5&D%¯ CENTRA~1.XLSpï¾&D6®&D%¯*ƒœ2**Central Dispatch Process Map.xlsx**m-lkÑÊ**C:\Users\ine\Desktop\Central Dispatch Process Map.xlsx**(

It appears that the content is there from which I should be able to extract the file name and types.

Here is my question, how do I migrate my attached files. I need to determine the content type and file names from the original data stored in `varbinary(max)`, I then need to move the files from the current location into my new table with the attributes that describes the file name and file type.

Thanks

Comment: Did the existing Access database have the filename or data type in a separate field? If so, you would need to use this value and store in a separate field in the new database. There really isn't any other way to determine file type just from the binary data.

Comment: No, in Access the field type was Attachment type, no separate fields are required in Access to store the type.